# Does firing off an indefinite WAITFOR increase the log file size?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, service-broker

In the last release of my app, I added a command that tells it to wait when something arrives in the Service Broker queue:

```
WAITFOR (RECEIVE CONVERT(int, message_body) AS Message FROM MyQueue)
```

The DBAs tell me that since the addition, the log sizes have gone through the roof. Could this be correct? Or should I be looking elsewhere?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Any active open transaction will pin the log, preventing truncation and eventually causing growth. If you start a transaction, write to the log and then wait forever in hope a message will eventually awake you, you just pinned the log and cause it to grow.

Lately I started recommending people to shun the WAITFOR in activated procedure, along with the loop. Just issue a RECIEVe and be done, let the activation mechanism loop for you (it does) and don't WAITFOR, just plain RECEIVE.

The WAITFOR flavor of RECEIVE creates a savepoint internally. This generates log (at least 3 log records) and does indeed pin the log in place while waiting. Having a long WAITFOR timeout (or worse, an infinite one) would be a very bad practice.

Comment: Would `WAITFOR (...) TIMEOUT 3600000` solve the problem?  E.g. release hourly.

Comment: Your log will grow *a lot* in one hour. WAITFOR (REC EIVE) is meant for intervals like 5 seconds...

Comment: You should also investigate why your transaction is actually active (has written log). The typical Service Broker pattern dow not issue any write before the RECEIVE.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  The transaction is active because I issued a `WAITFOR (RECEIVE...` Could you expand?  Perhaps, I misunderstood.

Comment: `begin transaction; waitfor(receive...)` will not generate any log records (will not 'activate' the transaction) while waiting, and thus will not pin the log. Only `begin transaction;[insert|update|delete];waitfor(receive...)` will cause the transaction to 'activate' (generate log records) and thus will actually pin the log while waiting.

Answer (score 5):

On SQL Server 2008 R2, if I execute a WAITFOR(RECEIVE), then run DBCC OPENTRAN, it shows the transaction as active, even in the absence of any prior updates.

Comment: Correct, the WAITFOR creates a savepoint internally and this triggers the log write so it does pin the log in place.

Comment: @RemusRusanu doesn’t that contradict [your earlier comments on the other answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30621/does-firing-off-an-indefinite-waitfor-increase-the-log-file-size#comment53348_30627)?

Comment: @binki that comment refers to SQL Server 2005. This is for 2008 R2. They behave differently with regard to this issue, if I remember correctly.